# Why does the frequency of an oscillator changes with the time duration of .TRAN command?

Tags: oscillator, ltspice, spice, pspice, ota

I have simulated an oscillator circuit using OTA in SPICE. It is a self starting oscillator.

However, the frequency of oscillation does not change with the bias current but changes with the duration specified in the .TRAN command. Eg - .TRAN 20ms and .TRAN 50ms will give oscillations of different frequencies.

[image]

Comment: Circuit please.

Comment: *Eg - .TRAN 20ms and .TRAN 50ms will give oscillations of different frequencies.* That might be due to the simulator changing the **timestep**. I suggest that you do what I **always** do and that is to set a **maximum timestep**. I usually set it such that there will be at least 1000 timepoints so for a 20 ms TRAN, I set max step to 20 us (or smaller). And add a schematic!

Comment: Added the schematic. I keep timestep to 25Ns for 20ms duration. The Oscillation Freq was supposed to change with Bias current not with the time duration but it's happening totally opposite.

Comment: There is a general rule for oscillator simulation: Select a minimum time step that is so small that the expected waveform (mostly sinus) can be fully recognized without remarkable edges. Then, the shown result does not depend on the selection (rule of thumb: App. 100 simulation points within one period)

Comment: How did you measure the oscillation frequency? If you read it off the output plot, are you sure the plot is not aliased?

Comment: Another issue is that the frequency is NOT changing with the bias current and capacitor value. It should change with these 2 parameters.

Comment: what frequency do you expect?

Comment: I think the schematic which the previous comments referred to was the one in LTspice. I might be wrong, but if I am, then I am asking for that. :-)